# Not allow to edit url

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am developing an Angular web app where I am having an issue with the routes.

Example, I have this url:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/orders`

and that is the default route, but if there is a playful user, and he does `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/orders/IAMPLAYFULUSER` or whatever he puts after `/orders` then my app crash.

so I need that if a user is trying to play with the url, he always is going to be redirected to the `/orders`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('orders', {
      url: '/orders',
      controller: 'OrdersCtrl as ordersCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'templates/ordersData.html'
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/orders');
})
```

there is my routing configuration.

Comment: Your routing configuration looks fine. I created a plunker using your config and it seems to work as expected, no crashes on url changes, you just get redirected back to the orders state: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQycBIwjbYE1k7D0DF7h?p=preview . Could you provide a plunker that crashes?

Comment: @Numyx just take into account that I don't want any user typing anything else in the url, nobody can't. That is all I need.